# get the values from pdo result

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the right syntax to output from `$user->find($id)` as key value fields. I cant seem to chain below.
eg.$result = $user->find($id) then $result['data'].
Using foreach doesn't work and using while starts a endless loop.

```
public function find($id)
    {        
        $this->data = $this->db->run("SELECT id,email,created FROM tblusers WHERE id = ?",[$id])->fetch();
    }
$usePDO = new basePDO(localhost);

$user = new doPDO($usePDO);
$id = 3;
$user->find($id);
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from `find()`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right! So in your function, you are not returning any data at all so even if your query or that whole function works, you will probably never know. so in your function, return `$this->data`

let me know if this helps, happy to sort it out with you.

Comment: using var_export/var_dump gave me the correct info inside the stdClass stuff. i dont want that - its seems like the long way round.

Comment: What are you talking about? You want to be able to call `$user->find($id);` and then it calls the `function find($id)` which also makes a search in the database and then returns the results to you isnt it?

Comment: thanks that worked. i was trying to assign the function at the call. cheers

Comment: awesome! Am glad to help. if the answer helped please mark/vote it as an answer to your question. Thank you

Comment: my vote is recorded but not displayed cos i just started